# How to create a dropdown menu on the left of parent?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I tried but it is too hard, so I would like your help...

I want to create a dropdown menu that is aligned where the left edge must be flush with the right edge of the main menu. In addition, the submenu should be on the same line. The problem is that I do not know how...

The only thing I could do, and absolutely position the submenu, but I think it is too difficult and I have problems when I resize the window ...

This is an example:

[image]

```css
a {
  color: #ffdf00;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #a0a0a0;
}

.block {
  background-color: #646464;
  border: 1px solid #505050;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  font-size: 1.045em;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.071em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

#block-system-main-menu {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: 30%;
}

.block .content {
  font-size: 0.94em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.block ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0.25em 0;
}

ul.menu {
  border: 0 none;
  list-style: outside none none;
  text-align: left;
}

ul li.leaf {
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  align-items: center;
  background: #646464;
  border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.sotto {
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  align-items: center;
  background: #404040;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

li:hover.leaf {
  background: #404040;
}

.stato {
  display: none;
}

.stato:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block-system block-menu" id="block-system-main-menu">
  <h2>Menu</h2>

  <div class="content">
    <ul class="menu clearfix">
      <li class="first leaf"><a title="" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Mappe </a>
        <ul class="stato">
          <li class="sotto"><a href="#">Aaaa</a></li>
          <li class="sotto"><a href="#">Aaaakkk</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="#">vulcani</a>
      </li>
      <li class="last leaf"><a href="#">Ciao</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fc1wggo3)

I hope that you can help me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely positioning the child `ul.stato` submenu within a relatively positioned parent `li.leaf` is the best way to do this.

See this [updated version of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/fc1wggo3/1/).
The key CSS here to note is below. You could also declare `right:` in a percentage, like `-100%` for a more fluid design.

```
ul li.leaf {
    position: relative;
}

ul li.leaf ul.stato {
    position: absolute;
    right: -88px;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
}
```

Once the screen size is below the width of the menu and sub menu, hit it with a media query to format it another way.

Answer (score 1):

I am of the same opinion as the Gent above but changed the menu to a fixed width keeping it fixed for display of submenu. updated here.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc1wggo3/2/)

```
.block {
    background-color: #646464;
    border: 1px solid #505050;
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;   
    font-size: 1.045em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.stato{
    display:none;
}
.dropdown:hover .stato {    
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left:150px;
    top: 92px;
}
```